# Connes' fusion product

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $B$ be a von-Neumann algebra and let $M$ be a right-Hilbert-$B$-module and let $N$ be a left-Hilbert-$B$-module. In this situation, Connes' fusion product $M \boxtimes_B N$ of $M$ and $N$ over $B$ is defined, which has a somewhat complicated definition using the structure of von-Neumann algebras.

*My question is: What is wrong with the following definition of a tensor product of $M$ and $N$ over $B$?*

Set
$$ M \otimes_B N := M \hat{\otimes}_{\mathbb{C}} N ~/~ \overline{\mathcal{U}},  $$
where $\overline{\mathcal{U}}$ is the closure of the space
$$\mathcal{U} := \mathrm{span}\{ m\cdot b \otimes n - m \otimes b \cdot n \mid m \in M, n \in N, b \in B\}$$
inside the Hilbert space tensor product of $M$ and $N$ over $\mathbb{C}$. This is the same thing as 
$$M \otimes_B N := \mathrm{HS}_A(M^*, N) $$
the subspace of Hilbert-Schmidt operators from $M^*$ to $N$ that commute with the action of $A$.

Comment: I thought the main point of the Connes fusion product was to tensor two _bimodules_ and obtain a _bimodule? In any case, have you looked at Andreas Thom's article http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/25/2/25-02abs.html which might implicitly address your question?

Comment: As far as I understand, the problem is that "even in the simplest case this space will be dense", see p253 (2) in Vaughan Jones, Fusion en algèbres de von Neumann et groupes de lacets

Comment: @MarcelBischoff: I don't understand... which space will be dense?

Comment: The $\mathcal U$.

Comment: This is certainly not true, as can be seen from the second description.

Comment: MatthiasLudewig: Well for one example: if M and N are infinite-dimensional Hilbert spaces that are irreducible G-modules for some locally compact group G, then the only G-homs from M* to N would be scalar multiples of the identity, which can only be Hilbert-Schmidt if they are identically zero. I guess that similar considerations may apply for certain non-irreducible reps, given the title of the article that @MarcelBischoff refers to

Comment: Link for the article mentioned by @MarcelBischoff: http://www.numdam.org/item/SB_1994-1995__37__251_0

Comment: @MarcelBischoff Why not write up the comment as an answer?